# How can I update properties of a data object based on user input?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, v-for

I have a simple problem that I can seem to solve. Here is the object I am looking to manipulate:

```
 [ { "expensesKey": "x", "expensesValue": 100, "subExpense": null },
   { "expensesKey": "y", "expensesValue": 100, "subExpense": null }, 
   { "expensesKey": "z", "expensesValue": 100, "subExpense": null } ], 
   "earnings": 300 } ]
```

I have a v-for loop that has a v-model to bind to the "subExpense" property like so:

```
div v-for="(expense, index) in expenseButton" :key="index">
     <input placeholder="expense.expensesKey" v-model.number="expense.subExpense"> </input>
</div>
```

***Problem:*** How can I subtract the "expensesValue" value and subtract the "earnings" value whenever the "subExpense" ***value changes from the user input***?

**Attempts:**

1. I created a button with a method that can do this with a click method
2. A computed method to add up all "subExpense" to subtract from "earnings"

```
 methods: {
  subtractExpensesValue(expense) {
      expense.expensesValue = expense.expensesValue - expense.subExpense;
      console.log(expense.expensesValue);
    }
},
  computed: {
    addSubExpense() {
      return this.expenseButton.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        acc += Number(curr.subExpense);
        return acc;
      }, 0);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify your button’s method and attach it to the input event of the subExpense input like this:

```
  v-on:input="substractExpensesValue($event, expense)"


  subtractExpensesValue(event, expense) {
    expense.expensesValue = expense.expensesValue - expense.subExpense;
    console.log(expense.expensesValue);
  }
```

#### Suggestion

Also you should change your placeholder mapping to `:placeholder=“expense.expenseKey”` otherwise you just assigned the text to the placeholder. Note the `:`

Comment: Is there a way I can set up an equation where "expense.expensesValue" is not subtracted by each number.  As of now if I subtract 11, it (100-1 = 99) then (99-11= 88) instead I need (100 - 11 = 89)

Comment: You need to denounce your input bind method, the way it is now, it updates on each keystroke. Take a look at the docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#debounce-Param-Attribute-for-v-model-removed